# OSMDroid Adding Marker

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am trying to add the marker dynamically (not static). Dynamically meaning, adding markers as and when I get updates from server.

So, following is my code for ItemizedOverlay:

```
private class VehicleItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlayItems = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public VehicleItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int pos) {
        return mOverlayItems.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        if(mOverlayItems!=null) return mOverlayItems.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(double longitude, double latitude, Bitmap bitmap){
        if(Preferences.DEBUG) Log.d("MapActivity", "Latitude: "+latitude+" Longitude: "+longitude);
        MarkerDrawable drawable = new MarkerDrawable(MapActivity.this, bitmap);
        OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem("a", "a", new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1e6), (int)(longitude*1e6)));
        item.setMarker(drawable);
        item.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER);
        mOverlayItems.add(item);
        populateNow();
    }

    public void populateNow(){
        populate();
    }
}
```

Following is the way, I am creating ItemizedOverlay & adding it to MapView in my activity onCreate():

```
mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
mVehicleOverlay = new VehicleItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stub), mResourceProxy);
mMapView.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
```

Now, whenever I get response from server, I am creating & adding overlayItems to ItemizedOverlay.

```
//onResponse is callback I received on receiving response. Vehicle is my vehicle object
public void onResponse(ArrayList<Vehicle> aVehicles) {
    for(int i=0;i<mVehicles.size();i++){
        final int lat = (int)(mVehicles.get(i).getLatitude()*1e6);
        final int lon = (int)(mVehicles.get(i).getLongitude()*1e6);
        mVehicleOverlay.addOverlayItem(lon, lat, bitmap);
    }
}
```

But all overlay items are overlapped over each other at center point of the map. Am I missing anything?

Also, if I add some static overlay items to mVehicleOverlay before adding it then it work properly.

```
    mVehicleOverlay = new VehicleItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stub), mResourceProxy);
final int lat = (int)(STATIC_LATITUDE*1e6);
final int lat = (int)(STATIC_LONGITUDE*1e6);
mOverlay.addOverlayItem(lon, lat, bitmap);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(mVehicleOverlay);
```

In OSMDroid, after adding custom itemized overlay, should I not add & populate overlayItems to it like we do in case of Google API v1? Or I am missing anything here?

Comment: the method parameter `aVehicles` is not used in your method `onResponse`.  Does replacing `mVehicles` with `aVehicles` in your method `onResponse` solve the problem?